# silent 7za compression

Tags: linux, compression

Without doing stdout redirection. Is it possible to have a silent run of 7za?

Comment: Can you mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 10):

Yes that is possible.

Just add **-y -bsp0 -bso0** to your command line. Those switches will disable progress, output reporting & assume yes answer to any possible questions, while still showing you any errors (which is perfect for cron usage).

Example:

```
7za a result.tar.7z -y -bsp0 -bso0 example.tar
```

From `7za --help`:

```
-bs{o|e|p}{0|1|2} : set output stream for output/error/progress line
-y : assume Yes on all queries
```

Tested to work on 7z version: 16.02.

Note, that version 9.20 bundled with some older OS (you can check your version by running `7za i`) doesn't support that feature. You can download latest statically linked binaries at the [official website](https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/).

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the output of `7za --help`, I don't think so.

Is there any particular reason why you don't want to just do `7za a archive.7z files > /dev/null`?

Comment: Not *quite* the same as *quiet* if that's what @romant wanted.

Comment: @pavium True, but since there doesn't seem to be an option to run 7za in quiet mode, it looks like the best option available.

Answer (score 1):

Side note: `xz` compressor uses the same algorithm 7Zip does (LZMA) but in a way similar to `gzip` or `bzip2` making it compatible with standard UNIX tools.

You can compress a file:

```
$ xz file.ext
$ ls file*
file.ext.xz
```

Or use it to compress a directory with `tar`:

```
$ tar cJf dir.tar.xz dir/
$ ls -d dir*
dir   dir.tar.xz
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap 7za in a script, so that the place that calls it doesn't need the redirection?